# Supervised Learning Classification Model Very Inaccurate

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression, nearest-neighbor

My classification model has very low accuracy. Even when I use a K-Nearest Neighbours model with neighbours = 1, the model still gets many things wrong. The logreg model has the highest accuracy, and it just predicts 0 for every sample. I am new to ML and trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. How can I improve the model?

## input:

```
# load the CSV file as a numpy matrix
dataset = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
target = np.loadtxt(target_data, delimiter=",")
# separate the data from the target attributes
X = dataset[:,0:6]
y = target[:]
print X.shape
print y.shape
#print X
#print y

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
print knn
knn.fit(X,y)
result = knn.predict(X)
print metrics.accuracy_score(y, result)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
print knn
knn.fit(X,y)
result = knn.predict(X)
print metrics.accuracy_score(y, result)

logreg = LogisticRegression()
print logreg
logreg.fit(X, y)
result = logreg.predict(X)
#every prediction is 0
print metrics.accuracy_score(y, result)
```

## output:

```
tshelley@tshelley-Ubuntu:~/Dev/Enterprise-Project$ python loadcsv.py
(700, 6)
(700,)
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
           weights='uniform')
0.674285714286
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
           metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=5, p=2,
           weights='uniform')
0.675714285714
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
0.72
```

Answer (score 0):

One huge problem I can see right now is that you're confused between [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) and [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification). So what are you actually trying to do, building a classification model or regression model, without sample data it's hard to determine.

Since you're using scikit-learn, try to look at their [cheat-sheet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) to get closer to what you're looking for.

FYI, without *any* pre-processing, a 67% classification is not bad.

Comment: I don't think there's any confusion regarding regression/classification. Logistic regression here is used as a linear classifier. I do agree that 67% accuracy without any pre-processing or hyperparameter tuning is indeed not bad. However, since the models were not tested on unseen data, I'd take these results with a grain of salt.

Comment: @abudis, I have to disagree regarding regression/classification. *If* `y` is a target class for those features, using the logistic regression method on its own will provide improper results. As the OP said *"The logreg model has the highest accuracy, and it just predicts 0 for every sample."*

Answer (score 0):

You should always make use of train/test split to know how well your model is performing on unseen data.

The reason for bias in output and high accuracy is because you have a class imbalance. Look at how you can use other robust metrics like precision, recall and fscore and know why accuracy fails over here : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/12/accuracy-and-its-shortcomings-precision-recall-to-the-rescue/

The best way to improve model is to balance the class distribution either by sampling the majority class or augmenting the minority class to match the number of records in majority class.